# A combinatorial problem.

Tags: combinatorics, measure-theory, entropy

Let be $(X, \mathbb{A}, \mu)$ a measure space, a partition of $ X $ is a disjoint family $\xi=\{P_1,\ldots,P_k   \}$  of measurable sets such tath $\bigcup P_i=X\pmod0).$

If  $\xi=\{P_1,\ldots,P_k   \}$ is a partition of $X$ or a cover of $X$ we define
$$
\xi^n=\{P_{i_1}\cap T^{-1}P_{i_2}\cap\cdots \cap T^{-n+1}P_{i_{n-1}},~~0\leq i_j\leq k,~~0\leq j\leq n-1 \}
$$

**Edit**:   $T:X\to X$ is a measurabe tranformation and  $P_{i_{j}}$ is any element of $\xi$.

**My Problem:**

Let be $\xi=\{P_1,\ldots,P_k   \}$ a partition of $X$ and 
$\eta=\{P_1\cup P_0,\ldots, P_k\cup P_0    \}$ a cover of $X$. Supose  that each element of $\eta^n$ intersect at most two elements of $\xi^n$,  show that:
$$
\operatorname{Card} \xi^n \leq 2^n\operatorname{Card}\eta^n
$$

Comment: I guess the $P_i$ in the partition and in the cover are the same, isn't it?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo  Yes!  :)